# How can i create mutable Strings in SwiftUI Text elements?

Tags: textview, state, swiftui

I would like to display a Text (view) in SwiftUI, that has mutable String content.

```
@State var myvar : String = "Undefined"
var body: some view {
Text("Content: \(myvar)")
}

func abc() {
self.myvar = "Defined"
}
```

Whenever I call the abc() function, the value of myvar doesn't get updated. I have checked this using a debugPrint(self.myvar) in abc().

This code is inside my ContentView.swift, while I am calling contentView.abc() from HostingController.swift in a delegate callback method.

Is there a solution to create mutable/changeable Strings for this "external" use in SwiftUI?

EDIT:

From HostingController:

```
override var body: ContentView {
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(contentModel)
...
return contentView
```

The last line gives the error ´Cannot convert return expression of type some View to return type ContentView´.
It is to note, that I am working in a WatchKit context, so this is an Apple Watch Application.

Comment: It should work, and actually does. Can you show how you call `abc()`? (I feel the reason is in it)

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the reply! This code is inside my ContentView.swift, while I am calling contentView.abc() from HostingController.swift in a delegate callback method.

Comment: This is it - you can change `@State` only within View itself.

Comment: How do I go about this then, @Asperi ? I would like to change it from the HostingController, because that class holds the logic to call abc(). Any idea?

Comment: Yes, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do via `environmentObject`

Create view model class to hold `myvar` state

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myvar: String = "Undefined"
}
```

Declare it as member of SceneDelegate

```
let contentModel = ViewModel()
```

Pass it to content view before adding to hosting controller

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(contentModel)
```

Change in other scene delegate (or other place passed by reference)

```
self.contentModel.myvar = "Defined"
```

Use in ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some view {
        Text("Content: \(viewModel.myvar)")
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation! This clearly seems to be the way to go here. I still have one issue though: After ´contentView = contentView.environmentObject(contentModel)´ I get an error ´Cannot assign value of type some View to type ContentView´

Comment: Where did you declare `ContentView` type? It should not be declared explicitly for contentView variable.

Comment: I edited my initial question with the declaration of the ContentView. As you can see I am working in WatchKit, so I need to return a ContentView object. A forced typecast via return contentView as! ContentView does not work, as it gives me the following error: Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<test_watchapp_WatchKit_Extension.ContentView, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<test_watchapp_WatchKit_Extension.ViewModel>>>' (0x28a18f8) to 'test_watchapp_WatchKit_Extension.ContentView' (0x672b0). This looks like a tupel to me, can I access only the first item?

Comment: I see. It needs to be wrapped into `AnyView`, like `WKHostingController<AnyView>`, `var body: AnyView`, and `return AnyView(contentView)`